# iOS TTTAttributedLabel Delegate didSelectLinkWithURL not getting called

Tags: ios, hyperlink, delegates, label

I'm having problems setting up the TTTAttributedLabel within my project.

I have set the protocol delegate in my header file

```
@interface TwitterFeedControlleriPad : UIViewController <TTTAttributedLabelDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateWaterfallLayout>
```

I have set the ViewController to it (is not nil, I checked already).

```
cell.tweetLabel.delegate = self;
```

It's showing all the links right in the label but when I tap them it's not calling the function.

```
- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithURL:(NSURL *)url
```

I've already used it before with success and it's exactly the same code!! It's driving me crazy!

Comment: How did you create the TTTAttributedLabel?  Is it in a storyboard or xib?  If so, did you set the "custom class" of the object (in the identity inspector panel)?  And did you hook it up to your IBOutlet?  Or did you create it in code and remember to add its subview?

Comment: Hi Nicholas, it is in a storyboard, I have two storyboards one for iPhone and one for iPad I did it first for the one for iPhone and everything works great, then I did the same for the iPad and it shows the label and the links but it doesn't fire the function. I created the TTTAttributedLabel programmatically and added it to a view through subview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved! The problem was the "User Interaction Enabled" Checkbox in the CollectionViewCell... It was disabled! it took me 4 hours to figured it out!! Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 50):

I understand it is not your case, but this is for everyone who have the same problem as I had and stumble on this thread.

I had an `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the same view as the `TTTAttributedLabel`. Because of the first one, the '`touchEnded`' function of the `TTTAttributedLabel` wasn't called, which is responsible for handling clicked links.

I solved the problem by adding the line: `tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;`

Comment: Totally had the same issue. My `TTTAttributedLabel` was working when I implemented it, but later down the line I implemented a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and didn't get a chance to test the adverse effects. This solved my problem - thank you!

Comment: You saved my life! Thanks

Comment: Thank you. This answer helped me so much. here's an upvote

Comment: you saved my life :D

Answer (score 4):

The `UILabel` `userInteractionEnabled` seems to be disabled by default, so unless you explicitly enable it, it won't work. That was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

One possible cause for the same problem (similar to Joeran's answer) is if you have a custom `UITapGestureRecognizer` on the view that keeps the `TTTAttributedLabel`'s tap gesture from being called. In my case I needed to block the tap gesture's action from being called if the tap was on a link, so `cancelsTouchesInView` was not enough.

My solution: blocking the tap gesture from being recognized at all.

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
tapGesture.delegate = self
```

And below the actual implementation of my class:

```
extension MyView: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        if gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture {
            let view = gestureRecognizer.view
            let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
            let subview = view?.hitTest(location, with: nil)
            // test if the tap was in a TTTAttributedLabel AND on a link
            if let ttt = subview as? TTTAttributedLabel, ttt.link(at: gestureRecognizer.location(in: ttt)) != nil {
                return false
            }
        }
        //else
        return true
    }
}
```