# Show URL inside a label text as hypertext with clickable effect in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label inside tableview cell and I need to show the url inside the label text as hypertext with blue colour and underline. The link should redirect to particular webpage on tap which means the default OS browser.

Comment: UILabel has no such feature.

Comment: @ElTomato Is there any library to implement the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use library such as the well known [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel). 
Basically, you add a label in storyboard, set its custom class to `TTTAttributedLabel`, and make an `IBOutlet` for it. Then, with some code, you add an action to some part of the text. In `Swift`, this could be this kind of code :

```
let name = "tomo"
let string = "My name is \(name)"
label.text = string
let nsString = string as NSString
let range = nsString.rangeOfString(name)
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.urlToRedirect.com")!
label.addLinkToURL(url, withRange: range)
```

Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857409/4894980).

If you want to automatically detect links in the strings, the library is also able to do it : [Links and Data Detection](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel#links-and-data-detection)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: How to identify the url from a label text and to show the url as a blue color link with clickable feature. The above codes add a url to an existing string

Comment: Okay, so I guess you don't know the string in advance (probably an answer from web service). TTTAttributedLabel has a feature to detect links in string. Take a look at https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel#links-and-data-detection, should be pretty easy to implement with above code :)

Comment: Thank you :) Highlighting the url is working properly.  But the function  didSelectLinkWith url is not calling, I have added the TTTAttributedLabelDelegate also. How can I add the click function when a user taps the url.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18645581/10005005 This solved my issue. Thank You So Much for your answer @AnthoPak

Comment: @Zeona Sorry, i've just seen your comments. Glad to see you've solve your issue. Would have been hard for me to help on your second issue, without code ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by a hack like customize `UILabel` as you want and add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to it.